# Is 应该9点多吧 a correct way of saying "after 9 o'clock"?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading a random book from the library, which contains:

> 阿紫：“昨天晚上他几点出去的，你知道吗？”
> 我：“**应该9点多吧**，和一个很像僵尸的人一起出去的。”
> <sub>仲尼，*谢谢你曾来过我的世界*, 2017, pp.11-12.</sub>

I'm skeptical that 应该9点多吧 is grammatical.  Clearly it means "after 9 o'clock", but my 语感 is suspicious about using 多 instead of 以后 or 之后.  I don't recall ever seeing that before.

**Question**: Is 应该9点多吧 a correct way of saying "after 9 o'clock"?

Comment: "9点多"is how we would say "a little pass 9" in English.  "after 9 o'clock" would be  九点后.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"after 9 o'clock" is 九点后. It can be 9:01 or 11:00 and even later

For example, If you go to a restaurant at 10:05 you could be told 九点后不供应酒精饮料  (No alcoholic beverages served after nine o'clock)

"九点多" means little later than 9:00 but not past 9:30 which is "九点
半" and definitely not past 10:00

九点左右 (around 9:00) could be 8:55 or 9:05 (not past 9:30)

Answer (score 2):

应该9点多吧 - should be a little beyond 9 o'clock.

The answerer saw the event at the approximate time. it lacked certainty as he/she didn't check the clock/watch, but a recall from memory.

The actual time could turn out to be earlier or much later than 9 o'clock.